# Naming each line in array in for each loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have multiple arrays, where I want to name each array at the end of the for each loop.

The code php code:

```
<?php
$csv = array_map("str_getcsv", file("translations/dk.csv"));
foreach ($csv as $line){
if ($line[1] != NULL){
    $line[0] = $line[1];
}

    print_r($line[0]);
    print_r("<br />");


}
fclose($csv);
?>
```

Example of the arrays.

```
Array ( [0] => Search and Save [1] => Søg og Spar på Hoteller ) 
Array ( [0] => Where are you going? [1] => Hvor skal du hen? )
```

Now the output of line[0] is each time the foreach loop runs naturally with a different value. But I need to name each $line[0] on every loop so I can access them afterwards. How do I do this ?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by name each $line[0].  It sounds like you might want to create another array outside of the loop that you can then add the renamed $line[0] elements to.

Comment: properly you are right, the issue is that when I echo $line[0] after the foreach loop is done, I will get the last value that was run through the for each loop - so I have no change of getting the value that line[0] the first time the for each loop ran. You follow ? So I need to give them a dynamic name each time so I can access every array after it has been through the for each loop.

Comment: Please, show example of output data.

Comment: Also, `fclose` is usless here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't use `file()` to split up the lines; CSV records may span multiple lines.

```
$f = fopen("translations/dk.csv", 'rt');
$csv = array();
while (($data = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
    $csv[] = $data;
}
fclose($f);
```

Second, to select the first column from the array you can use `array_column()`:

```
$results = array_column($csv, 0);
// "Search and Save", "Where are you going?"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for something like this:

```
<?php
$csv = array_map("str_getcsv", file("translations/dk.csv"));
$results = array();
foreach ($csv as $k => $line){
    if ($line[1] != NULL){
        $line[0] = $line[1];
        $results[$k] = $line[0];
    }

    print_r($line[0]);
    print_r("<br />");  
}

print_r($results);
?>
```